# How to resolve the following mysql query on partition by clause. I believe I am using the clauses correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, database, partition-by

```
query = """
        SELECT
            id,
            CAST(CAST(ts AS DATE) AS VARCHAR) AS param1,
            param2
        FROM (
            SELECT
                id,
                ts,
                param2_long_name AS param2,
                RANK() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY
                        id
                    ORDER BY
                        ts
                ) AS rank
            FROM (
                SELECT
                    DISTINCT
                    id,
                    ts,
                    param2_long_name
                FROM my_table
                WHERE
                    CAST(CAST(ts AS DATE) AS VARCHAR) > '2018-07-01'
                    AND id IN {ids}
            )
        )
        WHERE
            rank = 1
    """.format(my_table=table, ids=ids)
```

Getting the following error :
    ': (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'VARCHAR) AS param1, param2 FROM ( SELECT id, ts, param' at line 3")'

PS: querying mysql from python

Comment: Presumably, you are using a pre-8.0 version of MySQL that doesn't support window functions.

Comment: I am using a 8.0.13 version of MySQL.

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but: The casts in the inner `WHERE` clause seem unnecessary. The `DISTINCT` probably too, if `id` is a key.

Comment: @user3828311 . . . Perhaps some intermediate level thinks you are using an earlier version of MySQL.

Comment: Are you using version 8.0.13 for the client, but connecting to a pre-8.0 server? Try the query `SELECT @@version;` to confirm.

Comment: Confirmed. The server supports window function.

Comment: Updated the query with a simple casting change at line 3. Still running into syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write

```
  SELECT CAST(CAST("2017-08-29" AS DATE) as CHAR(12));
```

varchar is not supported.